# Casting a pointer to an int / Storing pointers to type T

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, casting

I'm hoping to count how many times a pointer is being used. I have a map:

```
static std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> counters;
```

When I want to insert a new value to it i'm using it like this:

```
template<class T>
MyClass::addPointer(T * tPtr){
    counters[((unsigned int) tPtr)]++;
}
```

Is it OK and safe to do a cast like this? It's not an expensive operation etc.?

Also, is this a suitable way to ensure each pointer only gets one count?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen Boost's `shared_ptr`? (Coming soon to C++11)

Comment: Yup, i'm implementing something similar for learning purposes

Comment: Just adding that on 64-bit systems a pointer is generally larger that an `unsigned int`. So using a `void*` is much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, you really don't need to cast it to `unsigned int`. You can have the `map` with `void*`:

```
static std::map<void*, unsigned int> counters;
```

Also a null check is important here:

```
template<class T>
MyClass::addPointer(T * tPtr){
  if(tPtr != 0)
    counters[tPtr]++;
}
```

Rest is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you should keep another map to avoid the cast

```
map<const volatile void*, unsigned int>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports the C99/C++0x type `uintptr_t` (defined in `stdint.h` / `cstdint`), that is the unsigned integer type specifically for storing pointer values as integers.

Otherwise, pointers can be used as keys themselves, as already mentioned.